# Can we use Css Grid frameworks with any design?

Tags: css, css-frameworks

What are cons to use Grid based approach? Where everything is in proportions?

Does it all make some restrictness? I'm not talking about non-sematic classes, unneeded css code, table- feel structure.

My question is about to work with fix proportions. in grid based system everything increase and decrease in proportions?

I think we can only use grid based framework if we are doing both thing PSD design and XHTML css coding?

Comment: Why down voting for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not designing the site, I highly suggest not using a grid or any other tools that would alter the design (proportionately or otherwise). Leave the design to the designer, and handle development, trying to get your finished design as close as possible to the finished mockup from the designer.

Nother irritates me more than when I have handed off a design to a developer, and he "adjusts" it because of some improvement he thought relevant.

If your designer doesn't use a grid, talk to him about it. If he prefers to continue without a grid, then don't force a grid on his design.

Comment: +1 I agree. I didn't get why he was asking about grids while admitting that he has no part in the design, or any authority over those that do.

Comment: @Doug Neiner- Thanks for answer. so I think we can only use grid based framework if we are doing both thing PSD design and XHTML css coding

Answer (score 2):

Grids don't increase/decrease things proportionally. They merely allow you to layout things in a nice and orderly fashion. I can't think of any cons to grid-based CSS frameworks. Perhaps they are overkill for some projects, but other than that they are terrific and should be favored by veteran designers.

Comment: but i do not make design in my company and i can't instruct designer. but how u r saying Grids don't increase things proportionally. can u explain this and read under the "The Grid" of this page http://wiki.github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/quick-start-tutorial

Comment: @Jitendra If you don't do the designs, why are you asking design questions? I just read "The Grid" and it says nothing about increasing items proportionally.

Comment: 10 px gutter is fixed, every column will span in 30 px addition. see my question i've mentioned already my view "I think we can only use grid based framework if we are doing both thing PSD design and XHTML css coding? " I think you are not getting my question or my question is not clear.

Comment: What does that have to do with increasing elements proportionally? You don't have to have elements 30px wide to put them in a 30px column.

Comment: yes but i have to make column 30 px . what if in design a cloumn has 31 or or 32 or 33 or 34 px. and gutter space like 12 px , 15 px